# xml validator source code in C

Tags: xml, format, validation

I am looking for a C source snippet to validate XML string fromat.
ex: 
Generalised source which checks for xml formatting. 

    10

must give an error for format.
Thnx

Comment: Do you mean validate, or check for well-formedness? "validate" has a specific meaning in the context of XML (ie: check that the XML conforms to a schema or DTD).

Answer (score 0):

[Expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/) is a widely used XML parsing library written in C. I've used this in many different projects and it does its job well and it's fast.

Comment: While expat is great, it's a non-validating parser. You can use it to check well-formedness (which may be what dusht wants, see my comment above), but if you really want to validate it's probably better to use a validating parser.

Comment: That's a good point, I had automatically read between the lines and translated "formatting" to "well-formedness".

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to include an external library, you can parse your xml with **flex/bison** (**lex/yacc**). An experimental code is available at the w3C: http://www.w3.org/XML/9707/XML-in-C

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to call Apache Xerces to check well-formatness and validation. If you are using MS platform, you can call MSXML.